# looping external commands in python

Tags: python, loops, process, multiprocessing

I'm trying to run a simple set of command line calls to a custom app, within a loop.

i.e.

```
list=['set1','set2','set3','set4']
ExternCmd = (myapp + ' ' + arg1 + ' ' + arg2 ' -v ')
for item in list:
    arg1 = item
    self.process.start(ExternCmd)
    self.process.waitForFinished(-1)
```

But I dont get sets 2 - 4 processed, only the first.

I tried adding a self.process.join() to get the loop to wait for the current set to finish processing,but I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'QProcess' object has no attribute 'join'
```

any help would be great getting my processes to work in order. I would ideally like them to be processed one after the other - rather than all at the same time.

thanks

EDIT: I put the ExternCmd in the wrong place for this example. My code should be:

```
list=['set1','set2','set3','set4']
for item in list:
    arg1 = item
    ExternCmd = (myapp + ' ' + arg1 + ' ' + arg2 ' -v ')

    self.process.start(ExternCmd)
    self.process.waitForFinished(-1)
```

This is still failing to run the command on anything other than Set1

Comment: `ExternCmd` is created before you change `arg1`

Comment: The code is incorrect `arg2 ' -v '` is invalid syntax. Post real non-working code. See [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Changing the args isn't changing ExternCmd. You need to set that in the loop, for example:

```
list=['set1','set2','set3','set4']
for item in list:
    ExternCmd = (myapp + ' ' + item + ' -v ')
    self.process.start(ExternCmd)
    self.process.waitForFinished(-1)
```

Comment: oops, in my haste to write a simple example I put ExternCmd outside of the loop. In my actual code it is inside - I'll update my original post